# Mockito: Runnable.run() of Runnable parameter passed to a method is not called

Tags: android, mockito

I am testing with Mockito. I Have a callback interface:

```
interface Callback {
    void onMessageRetrieved(String message);
    void onRetrievalFailed(String error);
}
```

Then, I have a method that accepts Runnable object that calls that Callback method:

Firstly, `interactor.run()` calls this method that calls postMessage:

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final String message = mMessageRepository.getWelcomeMessage();
        if (message == null || message.length() == 0) {
            notifyError();
            return;
        }
        postMessage(message);
    }

    private void postMessage(final String msg) {
    mMainThread.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mCallback.onMessageRetrieved(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

But line `mCallback.onMessageRetrieved(msg);` is never executed and so I get:

```
 Wanted but not invoked:
 callback.onMessageRetrieved(
     "Welcome, friend!"
 );
```

Why is `run()` not executed?

I am working with the project from this [articles](https://medium.com/@dmilicic/a-detailed-guide-on-developing-android-apps-using-the-clean-architecture-pattern-d38d71e94029). This is my Test class:

```
public class ExampleUnitTest {    
    private MessageRepository mMessageRepository;
    private Executor mExecutor;
    private MainThreadImpl mMainThread;
    private WelcomingInteractor.Callback mMockedCallback;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mMessageRepository = mock(MessageRepository.class);
        mExecutor = mock(Executor.class);
        mMainThread = mock(MainThreadImpl.class);
        mMockedCallback = mock(WelcomingInteractor.Callback.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testWelcomeMessageFound() throws Exception {
        String msg = "Welcome, friend!";
        when(mMessageRepository.getWelcomeMessage()).thenReturn(msg);
        WelcomingInteractorImpl interactor = new WelcomingInteractorImpl(
                mExecutor,
                mMainThread,
                mMockedCallback,
                mMessageRepository);
        interactor.run();

        Mockito.verify(mMessageRepository).getWelcomeMessage();
        Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(mMessageRepository);
        Mockito.verify(mMockedCallback).onMessageRetrieved(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: With which part of your test do you call `postMessage()`?

Comment: Hi, I have added details about that in description. Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
mMainThread.post(new Runnable()
```

But in your unit test, you have:

```
mExecutor = mock(Executor.class);
mMainThread = mock(MainThreadImpl.class);
```

That post() call receives a **Runnable** object. And I **assume** that your impl class **runs** Runnable.run() in some thread.

But: within your **unit** test, you are **mocking** all those elements.

You have to understand: `mMainThread = mock(MainThreadImpl.class);` doesn't create a *real* MainThreadImpl object. It returns something that **looks** like an object of that class; but this is a **mock**. It is completely **decoupled** from your actual implementation. When you do `mMainThread.poll()` ... nothing will happen. That **run** method is **never** executed. Because the mock object does **nothing** about that parameter when you invoke `poll()` on it.

In other words: you have to **configure** all your mocks. For example you can use an ArgumentCaptor and *capture* the Runnable object given to the post() method.

But of course, as that will be just some instance of an anonymous inner class, this will not help too much.

Long story short: you should step back; and do some more reading how/why you use mock objects...

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. I am actually reading now about Mock objects. Nice kick for me to do reading as well)

Comment: Glad to hear that. Too many people don't react that positively. They dont like to be told that their skill level requires upgrading.